# Symfony Class does not exist from Autoloader (User Providers)

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

The error is just a basic one. A class does not exist, and the error is actually very right. The class indeed does not exist. We're now working on Multi-Tenancy for this project, and there is where it currently gives up. This is the error;

```
Class "App\Entity\User" does not exist
```

It is a ReflectionException. For this we did a few things.

We have the following folder structure for our Symfony API-Platform instance;

```
- Controller 
- Messenger
- Entity
--- Main
--- Tenant
- Repository
- ....
```

And I bet that here is where the problem lies. The User Entity is not `App\Entity\User`. The Class is in the Main folder, so is named `App\Entity\Main\User`. However, when trying to use the app, it will always return in an HTTP 500, with the error message given above. It tries to find the class, which isn't there.

So, this is a bit different. We needed to change the provider for the authentication as stated in the [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers). We did this by modifying the `security.yaml` as stated in the documentation.

```
providers:
    database_users:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Main\User
            property: email
```

However, it still tries to use the other Entity. We've search the project, and there is absolutely no reference. We've emptied the cache and rebuild the docker-container, all to no avail. It still is looking for the class, which is not there, but in another folder inside there.

Are we missing something? The error Stack Trace is that it appears in the autoload_runtime.php, but even when dumping and regenerating this, it has no avail.

**Firewall from security.yaml**

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        # this firewall applies to all URLs
        pattern: ^/

        lazy: true

        # The user provider to use.
        provider: database_users
```

Comment: Under your firewall do you have `provider: database_users`

Comment: @Cerad yes. It is there. I've added it to the post.

Comment: It looks like you checked for all the horses so it might be time to try a zebra.  Introduce an error into services.yaml, maybe change the word `providers` to `providersx`.  Clear the cache and verify you get a big config error.  If you don't get an error then it implies that the security.yaml file you are looking at is not the one being used.

Comment: Just to check for wrong assumptions or miscommunication: did you move the User entity to the new namespace when you started the multi-tenant feature? Did it break then, or only after you added the security entry? Does another entity have an association with the User class, that may not have the correct `use` clause in its file and may still be located in the `App\Entity` base namespace? Can you provide the full error stack?

Comment: What namespace is in `App\Entity\Main\User::class` ? Maybe it's still `namespace App\Entity;` and not `namespace App\Entity\Main;`